# Selecting Multiple Columns using Google Sheets API

Tags: python, google-sheets, gspread

Sorry for my bad coding, I'm pretty new to working with API's. Anyways, I'm trying to get a range of columns from Google Sheets and display them to my console. For example, I want all data from columns A to D and just print them out to console. However, I noticed when using gspread I could only access 1 column at a time.

I would use:

data = workSheet.col_values(2)

and it would only allow me to select the second column. Then I tried:

data = workSheet.col_values(2, 6)

but it would just show me an error.

I was wondering if there was a way to print out a range of columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `col_values()`, try just [`get()`](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread.models.Worksheet.get) which allows you to pass a range in A1 notation:

```py
data = workSheet.get('A:D')
```

https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread.models.Worksheet.get

Comment: I solved the problem by doing data=workSheet.get('B:E'). Thank you though!

Comment: Sorry, I had actually meant to write `get()` in the formula code block itself. I edited my answer.